# How to transpose min/max value to columns in SQL Server using Partition?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, max, min, window-functions

I want to get the MIN and MAX from a certain values and put them in columns beside each other. Here's my query but I don't know how to transpose the values...

```
SELECT *
    , MIN([CID]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TID] ORDER BY [TID]) MinID
    , MAX([CID]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TID] ORDER BY [TID]) MaxID
```

Given:

```
TID       CID DATE
123456789 1   01JAN
123456789 2   02JAN
123456789 3   03JAN
123456789 4   04JAN
```

Result:

```
TID       CID DATE   MIN MAX DATEMIN DATEMAX
123456789 1   01JAN  1   4   01JAN   04JAN
```

Comment: Pivot is what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't simple aggregation good enough here?

```
select 
    tid,
    min(cid) min_cid,
    max(cid) max_cid,
    min(date) min_date,
    max(date) max_date
from mytable
group by tid
```

Or, if the `cid`s and `date`s are not changing accordingly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    tid,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then cid end) cid_at_min_date,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then cid end) cid_at_max_date,
    min(date) min_date,
    max(date) max_date

from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by tid order by cdate asc ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by tid order by cdate desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by tid
```

This orders records by `cdate`, and gives you the `cid`s that correspond to the minimum and maximum date. You can easily adapt the query if you want things the other way around (basically, switch `cid` and `cdate`).

Comment: Hi @GMB the results are not consistent there are some values are null in cid_at_max_date and max_date values the same as the value of min_date, by the way the date is insignificant though the CID is...thus, whatever the value of min and max that's it regardless of the value let's day CID 1,2,3,4 it could be 1=1jan, 2=1jan the most important thing is the min and max (1,4) and its equivalent date.Thnx.

Comment: @ThirdyLeon: ok, then as explained, just switch `cid` and `cdate` in the query.

Comment: Hi @GMB, sorry to bother you, same effect though.